# Holes in tabular borders

Tags: tables, multicolumn, border

I don't understand why but my tab has holes on the right border, and overlaps on the left one and I don't know how to fix this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.6cm,vmargin=1.6cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{|cc|}
        \hline
            \\
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\LARGE\textbf{Présentation de l'interview -- Année 2021-2022}}                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \\ \hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Contacts interviews pris par \\ (NOM(s) et Prénom(s) de(s) étudiant(s)) :\end{tabular}} & \textsc{XX} Romain                                                                                                                    \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Interview réalisée par \\ (NOM(s) et Prénom(s) de(s) étudiant(s)) :\end{tabular}}       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textsc{XX} Romain, \textsc{XX} Matthieu, \\ \textsc{XX} Fédi\end{tabular}                                \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\, \, Nom, Prénom du professionnel interviewé :\, \, }                                                             & M. \textsc{XX} Philippe                                                                                                               \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Fonction(s)/Métier(s) exercé(s) :}                                                                                 & Enseignant-Chercheur en Mathématiques                                                                                                 \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Coordonnées vérifiables :}                                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}- Téléphone : \texttt{02.XX.XX.XX.92}\\ - Adresse eMail : \\ \texttt{philippe.XX@uXX.fr}\end{tabular}      \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nom et adresse de l'établissement, \\ de l'entreprise, ... :\end{tabular}}              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}- Adresse : XX\\ - Téléphone : \texttt{02.XX.XX.XX.71}\end{tabular}                                        \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Date de la rencontre :}                                                                                            & Mercredi 08 Décembre 2021                                                                                                             \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Lieu de la rencontre :}                                                                                            & En ligne, sur ZOOM                                                                                                                    \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\LARGE\textbf{Difficultés rencontrées et solutions apportées}}                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \\ \hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trouver un créneau idéal pour que nous puissions être le\\ plus possible disponible pour interviewer M. XX.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                       \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
            \\
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\LARGE\textbf{Information essentielles à retenir}}                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \\ \hline
            \\[-0.5em]
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \\[-0.5em]\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: We can see the holes and the overlaping on the right and left side]

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: `\\[-0.5em]` whenever you see negative spacing you should be suspicious. never use negative spacing or `\\ ` after another `\\ ` or after `\hline`

Comment: if you use `{|c|c|}` as the default you can get rid of all the `\multicolumn{1}...` commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few problems with your solution. I recommended using the `tblr` environment from `tabularray` package. It has a much easier syntax for this kind of table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.6cm,vmargin=1.6cm}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={Q[c,m]Q[c,m]}, hlines, vlines, rowsep=4pt,
            cell{1,10,12}{1} = {c=2}{font=\LARGE\bfseries},
            row{1,10,12} = {rowsep+=4pt},
            cell{11}{1} = {c=2}{},
        }
        Présentation de l'interview -- Année 2021-2022 & \\
        {Contacts interviews pris par \\ (NOM(s) et Prénom(s) de(s) étudiant(s)) :}  & \textsc{XX} Romain \\
        {Interview réalisée par \\ (NOM(s) et Prénom(s) de(s) étudiant(s)) :} & {\textsc{XX} Romain, \textsc{XX} Matthieu, \\ \textsc{XX}} \\
        Nom, Prénom du professionnel interviewé : & M. \textsc{XX} Philippe \\
        Fonction(s)/Métier(s) exercé(s) : & Enseignant-Chercheur en Mathématiques \\
        Coordonnées vérifiables : & {- Téléphone : \texttt{02.XX.XX.XX.92} \\ - Adresse eMail : \\ \texttt{philippe.XX@uXX.fr}} \\
        {Nom et adresse de l'établissement, \\ de l'entreprise, ... :} & {- Adresse : XX\\ - Téléphone :} \\
        Date de la rencontre : & Mercredi 08 Décembre 2021 \\
        Lieu de la rencontre : & En ligne, sur ZOOM \\
        Difficultés rencontrées et solutions apportées & \\
        {Trouver un créneau idéal pour que nous puissions être le\\ plus possible disponible pour interviewer M. XX.} & \\
        Information essentielles à retenir & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularray output]

With `tblr` you can just enclose multiline content with curly braces and use `\\` normally for linebreaks. The style for `multicolumn` cells can be set in the argument of `\begin{tblr}`. For example `cell{1,10,12}{1}={c=2}{font=\LARGE\bfseries}` means, that the first `cell` in `rows` `1`, `10` and `12` should span two columns `{c=2}` and be set with `LARGE` and `bold` font.

Please have a look at the `tabularray` [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) for the other keys.

As a side note, it is better to use `\centering` inside `table` instead of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`.

Comment: +1 great answer

Answer (score 5):

With the `makecell` package and a bit of extra `\arraystretch` you don't need all the nested tabulars, negative newlines and multicolumns:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.6cm,vmargin=1.6cm}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{2.1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\LARGE\textbf{Présentation de l'interview -- Année 2021-2022}}\\ \hline
        \makecell{Contacts interviews pris par \\ (NOM(s) et Prénom(s) de(s) étudiant(s)) :} & \textsc{XX} Romain\\\hline
        \makecell{Interview réalisée par \\ (NOM(s) et Prénom(s) de(s) étudiant(s)) :} & \makecell{\textsc{XX} Romain, \textsc{XX} Matthieu, \\ \textsc{XX} Fédi}\\\hline
            Nom, Prénom du professionnel interviewé : & M. \textsc{XX}Philippe\\\hline
            Fonction(s)/Métier(s) exercé(s) : & Enseignant-Chercheur en Mathématiques\\\hline
            Coordonnées vérifiables : & \makecell{Téléphone : \texttt{02.XX.XX.XX.92}\\ - Adresse eMail : \\ \texttt{philippe.XX@uXX.fr}}\\\hline
        \makecell{Nom et adresse de l'établissement, \\ de l'entreprise, ... :} & \makecell{- Adresse : XX\\ - Téléphone : \texttt{02.XX.XX.XX.71}}\\\hline
            Date de la rencontre : & Mercredi 08 Décembre 2021\\\hline
            Lieu de la rencontre : & En ligne, sur ZOOM\\\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\LARGE\textbf{Difficultés rencontrées et solutions apportées}}\\\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\makecell{Trouver un créneau idéal pour que nous puissions être le\\ plus possible disponible pour interviewer M. XX.}}\\\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\LARGE\textbf{Information essentielles à retenir}}\\\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{-}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]